# Error while trying to attach .mdf

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to import the database with data from s3 machine to my local machine, for that I have detached the database from s3 machine and copied the database and pasted to local machine at the following path 'D:\Databases\MSSQL\OLTP\Data\Test_AS.mdf'
Now, When I try to attach this mdf file to SQL server instance, it is showing an error message:

```
Attach database failed for the server                                                        
Additional Information :                                                                     
     An exception occurred while executing Transact-SQL statement or batch
(Microsoft.SqlServer.Connectioninfo)                                                       
         Unable to open the physical file "D:\Databases\MSSQL\OLTP\Data\Test_AS_log " Operating system error 2 : 2(failed to retrieve text for this error.Reason : 15105)"."(Microsoft SQL Server Error : 5120)"
```

SQL Server has the permissions to do so with that location.

Comment: Does SQL Server have permissions to the location in question? Does the file exist exactly like that (excluding a file extension)?

Comment: OS error 2 is FILE NOT FOUND, which clearly indicates that either you've specified an invalid location for the file or there's an issue with the file name. Do you really have a file named `Test_AS_Log ` (with no extension and a space) in that location?

Comment: Are you trying to attach this to a **remote** SQL Server machine? If so, is the file **on that remote machine's D:\ drive** ??

Comment: Ken White,No it does not contain that file,actually it has to create the log file defaultly while trying to attach the database to SQL Server instance.But it is showing some error like above what i have mentioned. And also SQL Server has the permissions to that location.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify both the data file and log file when attaching them:

```
CREATE DATABASE DataBaseName
    ON (FILENAME = 'D:\Databases\MSSQL\OLTP\Data\Test_AS.mdf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'D:\Databases\MSSQL\OLTP\Data\Test_AS_log.ldf') 
    FOR ATTACH;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Turns out the reason of issue was that both .mdf and .ldf files were compressed because of D: drive had “Compress this drive to save disk space” checked.

[image: Compressed drive D:]

Also, I could not even create new database on D: because of this.
Resolved by unchecking “Compress contents to save disk space” for .mdf and .ldf files in Properties/Advanced…

[image: Decompressed ldf and mdf]